# How to check iOS application log on a jailbroken device?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to ready the iOS application log of a specific app or the entire system through SSH, similarly to Androids logcat function.?

Comment: May be this (https://medium.com/@pinmadhon/how-to-check-your-app-is-installed-on-a-jailbroken-device-67fa0170cf56)  is similar to something you need?

Comment: @Vipul not quite what I am looking for. I want to read the application log of iOS. Thanks anyway